# Proving existence and uniform convergence of a sequence of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Here is the problem statement I am dealing with. It comes from Royden $\S$3.3, 4th ed.

> **Problem 15.** Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $m(E)<\infty$. Show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ and a sequence $\{\varphi_n\}$ of simple functions on $E$ such that $\{\varphi_n\}\to f$ uniformly on $F$ and $m(E-F)<\epsilon$.

I have already proven that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $m(E-F)<\epsilon$. (This was the previous exercise.) However, I am not sure how to apply it to the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about $$\varphi_n(x)=\frac1n\lfloor n f(x)\rfloor\ ?$$

Comment: I can see how the sequence of $\varphi_n$'s converges to $f$, but I don't see how each of them is a simple function, i.e., take on only a finite number of values.